# Visual Studio load test- blank parameter values from csv causing tests to fail

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

[Screenshot of the empty value for data source parameter from csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUQUw.png)I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have a few web performance test scripts that I have built against a web application. I have data driven the scripts using csv files. All the web tests run fine for a few users and for all data sets. But when I run a 500 user test then many iterations for users fail (around 25% of user load) due to blank parameters being passed from the csv file to the test.

I have one controller and one load agent and both of them don't show any issues with memory or CPU during test runs. This is causing a great deal of issue during my test run as I can resolve it. This blank parameter issue happens only during a load test and not during a single user test. Also I have tried running a multi user single script test which runs perfectly fine. My parameter file looks like this

username,password
test1,password
test2,password
test3,password
test4,password
The problem is that all the data rows pass during unit test. I have run 1 iteration for each data row, so the data is genuine and fine. The problem only occurs when I run a load test with more that 200 users and then 25 percent of my transactions start failing after 30 minutes of test start. When I go into log files it shows that the context parameter value from csv did not have any value in it. Is there any setting in the load test which I can change/try which may restrict memory or something else which may cause this issue with load tests. Please note when I run the same script mix for 100 concurrent users the test runs fine. But when I run at 200 and above some transactions start failing. Also please note that 75% of transaction still pass.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank parameters"? Your example has blank lines, but does not have any blank parameters. Remove the blank (empty or whitespace-only) lines from the CSV. Please [edit] the question to show the error message that you are getting for these "blank parameters" and show the CSV line itself.

Comment: Hi Ahmed,By blank parameters I mean, no values are passed in the request to the server although the values are present in the csv file. There are no blank spaces or values in the csv file. Its a simple file in csv format .

Comment: There is insufficient detail in the question to try and answer you. Is the problem consistent, if the test is run multiple times then are the passes and fails always on the same lines. Please show the actual CSV data, provide two lines one that works and one that fails; indicate which is which. If you really want help then [edit] the question to include enough detail. Please also read [mcve].

Comment: Updated the description with more details

Comment: Show a screenshot of where the blanks occur, also show a screenshot of the context tab of the results. Make sure the latter includes the data source values. I think you are confusing data source values with other context parameters for dynamic data. If the test works for 100 users but not for 200 then perhaps you have found a limit with the web server being tested. This is the third time I have asked you to provide enough detail for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have added a screenshot to show the issue for failed users from test user logs. I know that its not a limit on the server as the request sent from the visual studio side does not have value from csv. Also I can't attach script or other screen shots as the tests were run on a pre-live environment so the information is pretty restrictive. I have been using other performance testing tools for about 10 years now but never seen this issue. This is my first project with Visual Studio as performance test tool.

Comment: That screenshot tells me nothing. How many lines does your CSV file contain? Is "SearchCriteria" the data source name and does the data source file name start "06"? Does the data source have other fields and, if it does, what does the context tab show for them.

Comment: Hi,the data source csv has just one column and hence just one parameter linked to it.

Comment: I asked several questions. I asked them for a reason. If you do not want help then please continue to avoid answering my questions.